# In a multiplayer game, does dying during a boss fight prevent you from getting loot?

Tags: diablo-iii

Possible duplicate question.

I was in a game with 2 other people and during the fight, one of them died. We ended up killing the boss, and then the person that died clicked the resurrect button to come back alive. However, she didn't receive any of the loot that the boss dropped. Is this normal? If someone dies during a boss fight, do they forfeit the right to the loot once the boss dies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it doesn't. You will receive both loot and experience from a boss (or any mob) kill even if you are dead.

Just have anyone still alive revive you and pick up your loot.

Comment: If that's the case, why didn't she receive any loot once she ressed? We are lvl 44 barb, wizard and DH, so none of us have revive. She just clicked the button once the boss was dead.

Comment: @Amberite everyone has revive, you just click on their gravestone thingy. As for why she didn't get loot, I have no idea, probably a bug.

Comment: lol, all 3 of us have been playing for 44 levels and we had no idea you can revive :P ... I'll just chalk it up to a bug, but in the future we'll definitely revive each other to be safe. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can NOT click on *revive* on your own when the fight is still going or you will not get any loot. If you click after the boss dies you will. ( because it has already dropped )

Comment: But she did click only once the boss died, and she still got nothing?

Comment: @Amberite Probably got bugged somehow, but yea not normal.